# CSS arrow at bottom of Bootstrap Jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I am trying to create a css shape using borders to represent the BLACK shape in the image below....

The black shape will sit inside (or over) a Bootstrap jumbotron. The red area is a background image.

[image]

I have been experimenting with the below code which gives me an arrow, but not the shape I need (which is two arrows perhaps?).
Any help appreciated.

```
.jumbotron:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 60px solid red;
  border-left: 50vw solid transparent;
  border-right: 50vw solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: you can take a look at bg gradient and background-size for a better look on edges , but i believe this is an SVG job :)

Comment: why does this need to be implemented with two seperate images? just set the image above as the background image and set the background size to "contain""

Comment: can you put together a live example?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/mXN8fyzh90

Comment: I love this fiddle, thks @Iwrestledabearonce.

Comment: this solution works too, but you lose the angle of the arrow as the screen width shrinks. why i was looking for something more flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using @IWrestledABearOne template, here is something with a kind of arrow at the bottom.

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/WgaUA2VjxN

**Css**:

```
.yomama{
 background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Zxn.png);
 background-size: cover;
  background-position: center bottom;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
}
.yomama-wrp{overflow:hidden;position:relative;}
.yomama:before{
content:'';
  width:150%;
      left:-25%;
  background:black;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
      top:100%;

      transform-origin:top center;
      transform: rotate(10deg);// translateY(-30px);
}
.yomama:after{
content:'';
  width:150%;
      right:-25%;
  background:black;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
      top:100%;      
      transform-origin:50% 0%;
      transform: rotate(-10deg);// translateY(-30px);
}
```

**Html**: Add a wrapper for the jumbotron :

Comment: Looks great @pbenard. seems to be working fine. Thanks so much.